# Intermittent NoClassDefFoundError for Kotlin class ProtoBuf$EnumEntryOrBuilder

Tags: kotlin, junit, noclassdeffounderror

In a run of our Kotlin JUnit tests on CI, we had a number of failures that errored with:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/metadata/ProtoBuf$EnumEntryOrBuilder
```

With nothing else in the logs to indicate what the problem might be.

The tests all started passing again on the next build from the same Git version, but it's a bit worrying as it's not clear why this might happen intermittently, and whether it might happen in production code. Wondered if anyone had any theories on what might be the cause?

We're using Kotlin 1.3.31 and JUnit 5.1.0.

Comment: Seems class path related but it's weird that it started to work again. Have you done some kind of modification in your dependency management (Kotlin version, jdk version) ?

Comment: The failures happen with the same Kotlin version, built/run using the same `openjdk` Docker image as when it passes. I guess it's conceivably a classpath ordering problem, I'm struggling to think of what else would give these symptoms...